# jQuery scrollTop() Resets to Top in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, scrolltop

I have noticed an odd behavior while using jquery's scrollTop in IE 9, 10 & 11. When the function is triggered, IE resets the page scroll position to 0, the very top, then it animates down to the correct section.  I am looking for a way to have the scroll behavior match that found in other browsers where it scrolls from the current position.  Here is my relevant code:

First, I bind the click event to my element:

```
$("body").on("click", ".marker", function() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        theAutoScrollingFunctions.scrollToTarget("city", 5000);
    });
});
```

Then my scrolling function:

```
$("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height()}, 500, function() {
      // Callback stuff
});
```

The scrolling technically works but in IE the page is reset to the top and then scrolls. I have tried placing `return false;` values throughout the process but with no luck.

Has anybody else seen this issue?

Comment: You have to provide minimalistic sample to replicate issue

Answer (score 0):

I use the same animate function when doing scroll-to sections on the sites I build. When testing in IE 8+ it works perfectly. Perhaps the `$(document).height()` is the part that makes the reset happen at the top?

This is how I like to do it:

```
<ul id="section-links">
  <li><a href="#section1">Scroll to section1</a><li>
  <li><a href="#section2">Scroll to section2</a><li>
</ul>
<section id="section1">
  <h1>This is the first section</h1>
</section>
<section id="section2">
  <h1>Another example section</h2>
</section>

<style>
  section{display:block;width:100%;min-height:300px;}
</style>

<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#section-links a').click(function(){
      var section = $(this).attr('href');
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(section).offset().top - 10}, 'slow');
    });
  });
</script>
```

As you can see, I like to add some space above the scrolled-to section, so the title and whatnot is not jammed up against the viewport.

I have not seen the bug you describe using this method.

Best of luck

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, however, this did not clear the issue.  I am trying to track it down and trace it but so far, no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seemed to be with my jQuery selector.

```
$("html,body").animate....
```

Changed to

```
$("html").animate....
```

This looks to have solved the issue in IE9+ and kept consistent behavior across the other browsers I have tested.